# First and last character of the string being removed

Tags: php, bioinformatics

I have created a function called checkfasta the code of which is give below

```
function checkfasta($seq)
    {
    if(strpos($seq, ">", 0) === "FALSE")
        {
        $dna = preg_replace("/[^ATCG]/", "", strtoupper($seq));
        return $dna;
        }
    else
        {
        $descst = strpos($seq, ">", 0);
        $seqst = strpos($seq, "\n", $descst);
        if(substr_count($seq, ">") == 1)
            {
            $seqen = strlen($seq);
            }
        else
            {
            $seqen = strpos($seq, ">", $seqst)-1;
            }
        $exseq = substr($seq, $seqst+1, ($seqen-$seqst));
        $dna = preg_replace("/[^ATCG]/", "", strtoupper($exseq));
        return $dna;
        }
    }
```

I am trying to extract a sequence from the user input. If the user gives a raw sequence like this:

ATGCTAGCTATTAGCTAGCTAGCTACGATCCAC

The program should take the entire string as a variable.
And if the user gives a sequence like this:

>Sequence

ATGCTAGCTATTAGCTAGCTAGCTACGATCCAC

The program should take entire sequence starting from the second line.

The above function was created to do that, but when I am using the function this way:

```
<?php
include "functions.php";
$seq1 = "GCTAGCTAGCTACGTACGACTGCTAGTAC";
$seq2 = ">Sequence
GCTAGCTAGCTACGTACGACTGCTAGTAC";
echo checkfasta($seq1)."<br>";
echo checkfasta($seq2)."<br>";
?>
```

This is the output I am getting:

CTAGCTAGCTACGTACGACTGCTAGTA

GCTAGCTAGCTACGTACGACTGCTAGTAC

The first and the last letter are being removed, when only raw sequence is given.

Can anyone please explain me where am I going wrong.

Comment: Couldn't you choose a shorter string as an example ? are we supposed to check the diff between the strings ?

Comment: Yes, for all us non molecular biologists [or geneticists or whatever] please use a shorter example string so we can make sense of what the issue is.

Comment: He already stated the problem. The first and last characters of the outputted string on the first line are missing. The two strings are the same otherwise.

Comment: I got it... still don't know the logical reason why it happened but it worked. I just made this change of replacing this line

`strpos($seq, ">", 0) === "FALSE")`

with this one

`strpos($seq, ">", 0) === FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks all for the replies.... if somebody can please explain why it made the difference....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be comparing the result of the strops() against a Boolean FALSE, not against a string with a value of "FALSE"

```
if(strpos($seq, ">", 0) === FALSE)
```

not

```
if(strpos($seq, ">", 0) === "FALSE")
```

**Explanation**

If `strpos($seq, ">", 0)` returns boolean FALSE, which you're then comparing (type specific) with string "FALSE" so PHP gives a false because the types are different.

If `strpos($seq, ">", 0)` returns boolean TRUE, which you're then comparing (type specific) with string "FALSE" so PHP gives a false because the types are different.

ie
Whatever the result of `strpos($seq, ">", 0)`, you'll always get a false, so the else will be evaluated

Comment: But why is it that using "FALSE" removed a character from either sides..? instead of throwing an error or making a blunder.

Comment: Because it isn't a syntax error: boolean false === string "FALSE" is a perfectly valid comparison that simply always returns a result of boolean false.

Comment: If that's true - either of them should have given the same outputs. But "FALSE" removed the first and last character of the string, while FALSE didn't....

Comment: `strpos($seq, ">", 0)` with a result of boolean false (i.e. there isn't a '>') will be compared (strict typing against boolean false, giving a true (`false === false` is true); so the `if` is valid and `$dna = preg_replace("/[^ATCG]/", "", strtoupper($seq));` will be executed rather than the `else` clause

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I've re written the function, it's still simpler and it checks for what you've mentioned in your comment:

```
function evenFasterCheck($seq) {
    $smash = explode("\n",$seq);
    if(is_array($smash) && count($smash)>0) {
        //it's seq2 format
        if(strpos(trim($smash[0]), ">") === 0) {
            return preg_replace("/[^ATCG]/", "", strtoupper($smash[1]));
        }
    }else {
        //it's seq1 format
        return preg_replace("/[^ATCG]/", "", strtoupper($seq)); 
    }
}

echo evenFasterCheck($seq2);
```

Comment: Actually the user can give anything in that line. The only thing is it should start with a ">" and all the description should be in a single line. The actual DNA sequence starts at the second line. This is a kind of format called FASTA that we Bioinformaticians use.